# Reading Web Service from android to read SQL Server ( Unable to merge dex )

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I already have Web Service and I want to read it from Andriod APP
I Added KSOAP2 ( New --> Module -- > Import JAR Package )
Then I edit Bundel.Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.medhat.test"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile project(":ksoap2")

    //api files('src/main/java/ksoap2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
}
```

But with all trials I got this Error Unable to Merge Dex ( I'm using Andriod Studio Ver 3.0.1 )

Comment: Why to use import, why not put the dependency in gradle like this for example: compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'

Comment: I tried to add this line compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1' but I got this error Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android-3.6.2:
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Medhat/AndroidStudioProjects/Mytest/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: can you post your full gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unimport ksoap2 project & put ksoap2.jar to lib folder just `

> **Clean -> Rebuild**

Answer (score 1):

you must add the repository as following:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
```

and the dependency

```
compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'
```